# Trying to Host Server for External Access - Apache, VirtualBox & Portforwarding

Tags: ubuntu, web-hosting, virtualhost, router, portforwarding

Banging my head on the wall at this stage.... trying to host my Apache site on Ubuntu 12.10 with VirtualBox. Running Windows 8 host.

Things I've done:

- Ensured Apache is listening on ports 80, 443 and 8080 (for thoroughness)

> ```
> tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:443 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 3355/httpd
>
> tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:8080 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 3355/httpd
>
> tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 3355/httpd
>
> tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:22 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 681/sshd
> ```

- VM is using bridged network connection
- Assigned a static IP to my Ubuntu VM, which can be accessed fine from within network.
- Forwarded TCP ports 80, 8080, 443 on the static IP of VM on my router
- Given my VM a static NAT Address
- Turned off Ubuntu firewall and router firewall
- Read on forums that my ISP (Eircom) allow port 80 to be used

And I still can't access my site using the WAN/External IP (checked internally and using [CanYouSeeMe.org](http://CanYouSeeMe.org)). It says all the ports I mentioned are closed.

I'm really at a loss of what to try next... Am I missing something silly here?

Note: I haven't assigned a static IP address within the router, on within the VM. And DHCP server is enabled. Is that bad?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! My connection in Ubuntu (eth0) wasn't using the right default gateway. It should be set to your router's IP address. Hope this saves someone else a day of headache.